# dataloader showing cpu time limit exceeded

Tags: data-loader, account, contact

I am facing one issue while using dataloader. I was upserting single Account records which has 2811 contacts using dataloader. But while upserting its throwing CPU time limit exceeded error. Then i tried to export some of contacts from my sandbox and i upserted account with 500 contacts then its working. Then i again imported 200 contacts and tried to upsert then also it was working. Later i imported all the contacts to total 2811(as before) and tried to upsert account, then also its works. But why it was throwing error at first??
I can not use the same workaround in production so its not working in production.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the trigger existing in the object in which you are trying to load the records.

Solution will be -
1. Deactivate the trigger and load the records. Once records inserted, Activate the trigger.

2. No need to deactivate the trigger. make the records insertion batch size to 10-20.

Comment: i reduced the batch size to 1 still its showing the error. and i dont want to deactivate the trigger. This error occures when i am upserting record.(In this case - update)

Comment: How manny related records are created or updated by the trigger. have you unchecked the Bulk load option.

Comment: 2811 related records are updated. Yes the bulk load option in unchecked.